# phpMyAdmin not working in Amazon Linux 2 after adding virtual host in .conf file

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, lamp, amazon-linux-2

I followed the below link and installed everything.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

I have some applications running and there are virtual hosts. All the application is running fine expect phpMyAdmin.

After removing all the virtual host in .conf file, phpmyadmin started working. When I add virtual host it didn't work.

My instance AMI is Amazon-linux-2.

Comment: Is PHPMyAdmin running on a different domain or it shares domain and is configured in a subpath, like yourdoma.com/phpmyadmin?